# Difference between client ID and Client secret in LinkedIn application

Tags: javascript, web, linkedin-api

I am newbie in development field. So, asking a childish question.
I want to integrate LinkedIn in my website for login. So, I created an application in linkedIn. Then, I got client ID and Client secret as Authentication Keys. Can you please explain the difference between them? Why should we not share Client secret? What can happen if i share it? What is the exact use of Client ID and client secret keys?
If you have any reference links, please share it with me too.
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

When making calls to the LinkedIn APIs you use two pieces of identifiable information: the API Key (sometimes called the Consumer Key) and the Secret Key (or Consumer Secret).

TheAPI Key is a public identifier of your application and the Secret Key is confidential and should only be used to authenticate your application on the LinkedIn APIs.

Since both the API Key and Secret Key are needed together to confirm your application’s identity, it is critical that you never expose your Secret Key.

If you expose your Secret Key. Then anyone can use your secret key and do some illegal things and you could be in trouble.

For more info see [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/best-practices#keysecret)

Answer (score 0):

To start we need two things

**API Key**: This is for your OWN application. Each application will get its own unique ID. This is used to actually verify that your application is allowed to use the API of whatever you are using (LinkedIn in this case)

**SK (Secret Key)**

This is a confidential key needed as a mixin of the API key for security purposes (Imagine if someone else got it, and had some access to the application you were developing!)

**Other Applications**

If you are familiar with Java, Java includes a SecretKey Interface which might help understand what I'm talking about [Secret Key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html)

Also check out the LinkedIn API

[LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/#!)